# What should I return if searchable element not found in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have a method, which search for some element in array. In Java it was "return null", but I can't do it in Kotlin. How is it correct to do this?
My method:

```
fun find(key: Int) : DataItem {
    var hashValue = hashFunc(key)

    while (true) {
        if (hashArray[hashValue].key == key) {
            return hashArray[hashValue]
        } else {

        }
        ++hashValue
        hashValue %= arraySize
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare in a function, that returned value could be a null.
Add a question mark after type (T?)

```
fun find(key: Int) : DataItem? {
var hashValue = hashFunc(key)

    while (true) {
        if (hashArray[hashValue].key == key) {
            return hashArray[hashValue]
        } else {
            return null
        }
        ++hashValue
        hashValue %= arraySize
    }
}
```

Comment: You have two unreachable lines in your example :)